# AngularJS and serverside filter and pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, filtering

I'm looking to use Angular JS with WebAPI - will be returning a large number of results from the WebAPI and so want to use some sort of server-side pagination and filtering.

Most of the tutorials i've seen are for client side filtering which isn't what i'm looking for.

Not really used AngularJS before, so looking for a simple example which can show how to utilise this - effectively i have a list of products and want to be able to for example filter by price. As it's a large data set i'd want to utilise pagination as well.

At the moment, in my controller I have:

```
    app.controller("MyController", function ($scope, $http){


     $http.get('/api/ProductResults').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.results = data.results;

         }).
          error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // log error

      });
```

which will return a list of products and i will use  to output a list.

The WebAPI will take parameters for page number and filters etc. but i'm not sure how to implement this in the code.

```
    $http.get('/api/Products?page=1&minPrice=10')
```

I'd expect that i would get the current page number and min price from the URL parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the page number and minPrice, you could have scope variables that hold that info for you. Let's say you have a data grid on the page that includes navigation for the several pages of data you have. In this case, I would have a $scope.pageNumber variable bound to that data grid navigation item. A click on next or previous changes the value of $scope.pageNumber and on you $http you would use that $scope.pageNumber when constructing your request URL. The same goes for minPrice.

You can add your parameters to your request like this:

```
$http({
    url: "/api/Products", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {page : 1, minPrice : 10}
 });
```

Comment: is there anyway to get the parameter values from the URL of the current page?

So if i have  index.html/?page=1  that would feed into the $http method?

Comment: yes, you can inject the $routeParams service on your controller. it'll contain your routes url parameters in the form {page: 1, minPrice: 10}